# Hide everything before a found string

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I've got an HTML page with automatically generated content which I cannot change - a weekly schedule to be precisely. Nevertheless I would like to hide expired information - everything before the current date.

Unfortunately the generated content is rarely formated. There are no divs or other parent and child tags to hook in.

Is there a way to hide everything before a found string, e.g. the line " ", meaning "2" for Tuesday, with an changing index of course, or the current date.

I've got a bit JS experience and tried with jQuery without success. Since there are no parents, siblings or children, I don't know what to .hide()

```html
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<CENTER><font size="3" face="Arial">
<BR><div id="schedule">
<a name="1">&nbsp;</a><br><b>25.11. Montag</b> | <a href="#2">[ Dienstag ]</a> | <a href="#3">[ Mittwoch ]</a> | <a href="#4">[ Donnerstag ]</a> | <a href="#5">[ Freitag ]</a><p>
<table class="subst" >
<tr><td align="center" colspan="9" >yesterdays information</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<a name="2">&nbsp;</a><br><a href="#1">[ Montag ]</a> | <b>26.11. Dienstag</b> | <a href="#3">[ Mittwoch ]</a> | <a href="#4">[ Donnerstag ]</a> | <a href="#5">[ Freitag ]</a><p>
<table class="subst" >
<tr><td align="center" colspan="9" >todays information</td></tr>
</table>
.....
</div>
</body>
```

This is content of the generated page. I can only add content to a template but cannot change the generated content itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd have the generating side do this rather than chase it in the browser.  Unless someone uses a lot of discpline in generating the content lines themselves (which you imply they aren't), there's no good way of universally attacking this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the software that is used to generate the content doesn't have this option

Comment: Okay, let me think on this.  There might be a way to lexically scan it.  I have a few hours I can spend on this before I have to start the holiday cooking.

Comment: I have the start of a solution at http://www.blindedbyscience.net/SO/grayout.html.  This removes the table for dates already in the past.  It's very tied to the layout of the content; it also assumes that there's a one-to-one match of bold tags to table tags.  I can fine-tune this a lot more so that it only looks at bold tags with dates in them and uses only tables with the "subst" class.  In fact, by the time you read this, I might already have done that.  There's also a version at http://jsfiddle.net/cVtS8/.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cVtS8/1/ is smarter.  The only thing remaining is to walk the tag chain and hide the day-of-week elements you don't want to see.  Might have to save that until after I start some of the cooking.

Comment: Different approach this time, and it works better: http://www.blindedbyscience.net/SO/grayout2.html and http://jsfiddle.net/cVtS8/2/

Comment: looks quite complicated but I think I get the point. I also tried to load the content into an array but I didn't know scan it for the information I needed. Thank you - I will test it at work tomorrow.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, it looks a little complicated.  I might try refining it further today...I can probably consolidate the logic a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have body element, you can hide it. Check this out:

```
$('body').hide();
```

Comment: very funny - not helpful